# Is it possible to enforce a type constraint on a class instance for a higher-kinded type?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-constraints, higher-kinded-types

I have a type defined like this:

```
newtype PrimeSet a = P Integer
    deriving Eq
```

I have also defined a function which converts a prime set to a list, given that its type parameter is an `Integral`.

```
toList :: Integral a => PrimeSet a -> [a]
```

I now what to give `PrimeSet` a `Foldable` instance, so this was my first attempt (after importing `fold` from `Data.Foldable`):

```
instance Foldable PrimeSet where
    foldMap f = fold . map f . toList
```

This didn't work, however, and the compiler told me that it `Could not deduce (Integral a) arising from a use of ‘toList’`. My understanding of this message is that `toList` requires its argument to be an `Integral a => PrimeSet a` type, but this isn't necessarily the case in the `Foldable` instance.

The message also said that a possible fix would be to add `Integral a` to the context of the type signature for my `foldMap` implementation, but of course I was then told that I'm not allowed to provide my own type definitons for class methods unless I use `InstanceSigs`, so I tried that but that didn't seem to work either.

So my question is this: is it possible to add a type constraint to a class instance if the type parameter of the type I'm writing the class instance for is hidden - or, to reiterate, can I do something like this?

```
instance (Integral a) => Foldable (PrimeSet a) where
```

(This of course doesn't work because `PrimeSet a` has the kind `*` whereas `Foldable` requires `* -> *`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The whole point of higher-kinded types is to work over *any* parameter type. Whereas `PrimeSet` isn't really parametric at all – basically, it's *always* `PrimeSet Integer`. Why do you have that `a` parameter at all?

There is however a different class for types that are “kinda containers”, but not for arbitrary types: [MonoTraversable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable), or actually [MonoFoldable](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.11.0/docs/Data-MonoTraversable.html#t:MonoFoldable) in this case.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.MonoTraversable

type instance Element (PrimeSet a) = a
-- or, if `PrimeSet` is not parameterised,
-- type instance Element PrimeSet = Integer

instance (Integral a) => MonoFoldable (PrimeSet a) where
  otoList = YourImplementation.toList
```

An alternative would be that you do use parameterised types, functors in fact, but not in the normal **Hask** category of *all* Haskell types but only in the subcategory whose type<del>s</del> <del>are</del>is `Integer`. I have such a class [in my constrained-categories package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.3.1.1/docs/Data-Foldable-Constrained.html). But, especially for this type you have, this really doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: Well the reason I introduced the type parameter was initially so I could make it an instance of `Foldable`. But it's used elsewhere (e.g. another function: `toList :: Integral a => PrimeSet a -> [a]`), though this isn't actually needed because it would work just as well on an unparameterised `PrimeSet` type. The reason the type is declared as `P Integer` isn't because the set itself stores an integer, but in fact because the `Integer` value actually encodes a set of any amount of `Integral` values, if that makes sense.

Comment: Ok. Well, ditch the `a` parameter then and make it simply `instance MonoFoldable PrimeSet`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a GADT to constrain the parameter type:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data PrimeSet a where
    PrimeSet :: Integral a => Integer -> PrimeSet a

instance Foldable PrimeSet where
    foldr f b (PrimeSet x) = f (fromInteger x) b
```

You could generalise a little with ConstraintKinds (and the monofoldable class):

```hs
data Monomorphic f c a where
    Monomorphic :: c a => f -> Monomorphic f c a

instance (item ~ Item f, MonoFoldable f) => Foldable (Monomorphic f ((~) item)) where
    foldr f b (Monomorphic xs) = ofoldr f b xs

data PrimeSet = PrimeSet Integer

instance Foldable (Monomorphic PrimeSet Integral) where
    foldr f b (Monomorphic (PrimeSet i)) = f (fromInteger i) b
```